# Restructure json based on actual and expected data

Tags: node.js, json, node-modules, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I want to restructure json based on original json data and the expected json data.

If you look closely in the original json data I have country outside of the Male/Female attributes. I would want the country module to be inside the Male/ Female attribute based on the orientation attribute inside the country module. So in the afterdata I would have 1 country module in Male attribute(since there is 1 male record) and 2 country module in Female attribute(since there are 2 female records).

Original json data looks like this:

```
{
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected json data:

```
{ 
  "Implementations":    [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"         
         "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Male",          
                  "Name": ABCD
                }
            ],
              "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]

      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"          
        "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": EFGH
                },
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": IJKL        
                }
              ],
        "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ]

}
```

Program:

```
 var Implementations = {  
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var output = [];
for (k in Implementations.Implementations.Male) {
  var temp = [];  
  for (j in Implementations.Implementations.Male[k]) {
    temp.push({
      Country: j      
    });
  }
  output.push({
    "Implementations": k,
    Country: temp
  });
}
console.log(output);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Do you want a Node.js program to do the conversion? What is the current program?

Comment: My question is how to restructure to the expected payload from the existing payload using nodejs.

Comment: OK. What Node.js program have you written?

Comment: @shaochuancs-I have updated the question with the program that loops through Implementations.

Comment: @shaochuancs I have added another question titled "Rearrange json missing elements". Can you help tweak the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not work because `Implementations.Implementations` is an array, it doesn't have field named `Male`.

Here is a working code snippet:

```
//Original JSON data in question.
var Implementations = {  
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// Program that make the conversion
var finalResult = [];
for (var i=0; i<Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
  var currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];
  var targetObj = {
    "Male": {
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    },
    "Female": {
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    }
  };
  for (var j=0; j<currentImplementation.Country.length; j++) {
    var currentCountry = currentImplementation.Country[j];
    if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Male') {
      targetObj.Male.Country.push(currentCountry);
    } else if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Female') {
      targetObj.Female.Country.push(currentCountry);
    }
  }
  finalResult.push(targetObj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult));
```

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your quick response. Also, will using node-Json-transform be an easier way to restructure? I haven’t tried it yet, let me know your suggestions.

Comment: I think using Node would be easier to transform JSON, but anyway that’s opinion based. Also, if this answer helps and fixed the problem, would you kindly mark it as valid?

Comment: Ah, you’re asking Node module “node-json-transform”. I think this is a pretty easy convert, and not necessary to introduce a new module. But if you have a lot of similar convert work, maybe using a module is a good idea.

Comment: How do I rename a property key? In the example above, Country, State are property keys. How do I rename State to Statecount?